# Style paragraph with class of lead

Tags: html, css

If I wanted to style h1 in a div with a class of example, I would go `div.example h1`

However, why is it when I want to style any paragraph with a class of lead, I would do `p.lead` instead of `lead.p`? Shouldn't the p be similar to the h1 in first paragraph?

Thank you.

Comment: No `lead.p` mean `<lead class="p"></lead>` while `p.lead` is to select `<p class="lead"></p>`

Comment: Generally, it's always the tag first then the class, then tag, then class, then tag then class. You get the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your h1 style structure is like:

```
<div class="example">
   <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

while for `lead.p`.. you need to have a tag like :-

```
<lead class="p"></lead>
```

No lead tag in html .

for `p.lead`, tags will be like:-

```
<p class="lead"></p>
```

hope you find the difference now.

Answer (score 2):

Tag is always first followed by attributes when writing styles for your tag elements. If you want to style an attribute, you miss out the tag and just type .className or #idName

```css
p{
  font-size: 20px;
}


p#hello-world {
  color: blue;
}

p.hello-world {
  color: red;
}

p.hello-world.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}

.bold{
  font-weight: bold;
}

#bye{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<pre>p</pre>
<p>Hello World</p>

<pre>p#hello-world - p tag with id 'hello-world'</pre>
<p id="hello-world">Hello World</p>

<pre>p.hello-world - p tag with class 'hello-world'</pre>
<p class="hello-world">Hello World</p>

<pre>p.hello-world.italic - p tag with class 'hello-world' and italic</pre>
<p class="hello-world italic">Hello World</p>

<pre>.bold - any tag with class 'bold'</pre>
<div class="bold">Hello World</div>

<pre>#bye - any tag but only the first as id's should
be unique (use class instead if you want to target
multiple elements) with id 'bye'</pre>
<div id="bye">Hello World</div>
```